# Angularjs/CodeIgniter: ng-include

Tags: codeigniter, angularjs

Using the Angularjs Bootstrap UI, I have created a series of tabs/panes. I use the following controller to hold details for the $scope.panes

```
function imageGalleryCtrl ($scope, images)
{
    $scope.panes = [
        { title:"Home", content:"create.php", active: true },
        { title:"Upload", content:"Dynamic content 2"}
    ];
}
```

The HTML for the tabs/panes looks like this:

```
<pane active="pane.active" heading="{{pane.title}}" ng-repeat="pane in panes">
            <div ng-include="pane.content"></div>
        </pane>
    </tabs>
```

The tabs work and display properly. The current error is a 404, not found. If I type the absolute URL I get 403, forbidden....

What is the proper way to declare the path for the include?

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude), try wrap the template name in quotes. Something like `content:"'create.php'"`

> ngInclude|src – {string} – angular expression evaluating to URL. If
>   the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in quotes, e.g.
>   src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".

Comment: content:"create.php" should contains the path like content:"<path>/create.php" from the the root html. please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pane active="pane.active" heading="{{pane.title}}" ng-repeat="pane in panes">
            <div ng-include="{{pane.content}}"></div>
</pane>
```

Beware though, it will not work with the second object in your array since it's not a real file path, you may want to structure your data differently.

e.g.

```
<pane active="pane.active" heading="{{pane.title}}" ng-repeat="pane in panes">
            <div ng-include="{{pane.url}}"><p>{{pane.content}}</p></div>
</pane>

    $scope.panes = [
        { title:"Home",
          url: "create.php",
          content:"copy copy copy", active: true
         },
        { title:"Upload",
          url:"",
          content:"Dynamic content 2",
           active:false
        }
    ];
```